# Mutex can deference struct's but not primitives

Tags: rust

The following code in which a struct `Counter` wraps a `u32`. I am using `Arc` to wrap and `Mutex` to allow safe and shared access to the value. I have omitted the threaded code to provide a simple example:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

fn main() {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    struct Counter {
        count: u32,
    }

    let counter = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Counter { count: 0 }));

    for _ in 0..10 {
        let mut c_int = counter.lock().unwrap();
        c_int.count += 1;
    }

    println!("{:?}", counter.lock().unwrap());
}
```

Here `counter.lock().unwrap()` is able to transparently lock the mutex and unwrap the result and I don't need to dereference the `Arc`. Also dereference on `c_int` works transparently.

Consider following code where `Counter` is replaces with `u32`:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

fn main() {
    let counter = Arc::new(Mutex::new(32));

    for _ in 0..10 {
        let mut c_int = counter.lock().unwrap();
        c_int += 1;
    }

    println!("{:?}", counter.lock().unwrap());
}
```

It wouldn't compile because `c_int += 1` is not valid as it doesn't derefernces to u32.

My questions are:

1. Why structs are special while primitives are not while using through a smart pointer like `Mutex`?
2. How I can use functions of `Mutex` directly on an `Arc`?

I think both have to do with `Deref` but not sure how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`c_int` is not actually the integer or `Counter` instance, it's a `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, T>`.

The reason why `c_int.count += 1;` works in the first example is `Deref` coercion: Wherever it sees an expression such as `foo.bar`, the compiler checks if `foo` has a member `bar`, and if it doesn't, it dereferences it, and tries again. In your case, because `c_int` is a mutex guard, it doesn't have a `count` member, the compiler will try `(*c_int).count`.

Now, `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, T>` does implement `Deref<Target=T>`, which in your case means you can get a `Counter` out of the mutex guard, and the compiler stops there.

However, in the integer case, you only have `c_int += 1`, assignment by itself does not trigger `Deref` coercion, so the compiler rightfully gives you an error

```
8 |         (c_int) += 1;
  |         -------^^^^^
  |         |
  |         cannot use `+=` on type `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, {integer}>`
```

To get the second example to work, you have to dereference yourself:

```rust
*c_int += 1;
```

See also:

- [What are Rust's exact auto-dereferencing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules)

Comment: Thanks :-) I kinda knew this but still need pedantic explanation!